# Reopening a closed file stream

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Consider the following code,

```
auto fin = ifstream("address", ios::binary);
if(fin.is_open()) 
    fin.close()
for(auto i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    fin.open()
    // ....
    // read (next) b bytes...
    // ....
    fin.close()
    // Some delay
}
```

The code above can't be implemented in the C++ I know, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do so?

Here are my requirements:

- When reopening the file, there would be no need to pass the parameters (path and mode) again.
- When reopening the stream, it continues from the point in the stream that it was when got closed.

#### Clarification

- The files I work with are big in size and in a point of time other threads from third party libraries may decide to (re)move them. An open stream will prevent such actions.
- Continuously reading a big file will slow down the system.

Comment: That's not how streams work. Why close it if you want it open and positioned?

Comment: @BoPersson The files I work with are big in size and in a point of time other threads from third party libraries may decide to remove them. An open stream will prevent this action and those threads may fail.

Comment: Setting yourself up for a concurrency nightmare here. Recommend a rethink.

Comment: Deleted my answer since I don't remember enough C++ to continue answering. You could always create a function that takes the constructor arguments, and returns a new function that takes a stream, and creates a new one where the old one left off. Probably the easiest way to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I appreciate the time you dedicated to answer. Thank you. I took an idea from what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The need**

Indeed, a file can't be deleted by another process as long as a stream keeps it open.

I suppose you have already asked yourself these questions, but fo the recors I have to suggest you to think about it:

- Can't the file be read into (virtual) memory and discarded when no longer needed ?
- Can't the file processing be pipelined asynchronously, to read it at once and process it without unnecessary delays ?
- What to do if the file can no longer be opened because it was deleted by the other process ?  What to do if the location can't be found, because the file was modified (e.g. shortened) ?
- If you would have the perfect solution to your issue, what would be the effect if the other process would try to delete the file when it is open (only for a short time, but nevertheless open and blocking the deletion) ?

**The solution**

Unfortunately, you can't achieve the desired behavior with standard streams.  You could emulate it by keeping track of the filename and of the position (and more generally of the state):

```
   auto mypos = ifs.tellg();  // saves position.  
                              // Should flag be saved as well ? and what about gcount ?
   ifs.close();  

   ...

   if (! ifs.is_open()) {
       ifs.open(myfilename, myflags);  // open again !  
       if (! ifs) { 
           // ouch ! file disapeared ==> process error 
       }
       ifs.seekg(mypos);              // restore position 
       if (! ifs) { 
           // ouch ! position no longer reachable  ==> process error 
       }
   }
```

Of course, you wouldn't like to repeat this code ever and ever. And it would not be so nice having all the sudden a lot of global variables to keep track of the stream's state. But you could very easily encapsulate it in a wrapper class that would take care of saving and restoring the stream's state using existing standard operations.

Comment: Even if the file is open, it may be truncated to zero size by other processes, and its directory entry may be removed. What is the intended operating system?

Comment: @HeikoBloch yes, and we won't solve all of OP's challenges here.  I think OP targets windows due to "visual C++" tag

Comment: Thank you. The questions you asked, I had them in mind. Unfortunately the risks you have mentioned all exists and I had no better solution than that you gave. It seems there is no other or better solution. Thank you again.